# How to tune the following Oracle10g query?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I'd written a query to get some overlapping digits range from my_codes table. The query is...

```
select distinct t1.destination,
                      t1.digitsmin,
                      t1.digitsmax,
                      t2.destination,
                      t2.digitsmin,
                      t2.digitsmax,
                      'S'
        from my_codes t1
        join my_codes t2
          on t1.rownumber <> t2.rownumber
         and t1.typ = t2.typ
       WHERE t1.mycarr= 73
         and t1.typ = 'S'
         AND (t2.DigitsMin <= t1.DigitsMin AND t2.DigitsMax > t1.DigitsMin and
             t2.DigitsMax < t1.DigitsMax OR
             (t2.digitsmin > t1.digitsmin and t2.digitsmax <= t1.digitsmin) OR
             (t2.digitsmin >= t1.digitsmin and t2.digitsmax < t1.digitsmax) OR
             (t2.digitsmin > t1.digitsmin and t2.digitsmax <= t1.digitsmax) OR
             (t2.digitsmin > t1.digitsmin and t2.digitsmin <= t1.digitsmax and
             t2.digitsmax > t1.digitsmax));
```

`my_codes` Table data is

```
mycarr  typ  rownumber destination digitsmin digitsmax
73       S    1         AAA        8875       8880
73       S    2         AAA1       8870       8880
73       S    3         AAA2       8875       8878
73       S    4         AAA3       8876       8880
```

If the table has more data its taking lot of time. Could someone help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to simplify it to just this:

```
select distinct t1.destination,
                      t1.digitsmin,
                      t1.digitsmax,
                      t2.destination,
                      t2.digitsmin,
                      t2.digitsmax,
                      'S'
        from my_codes t1
        join my_codes t2
          on t1.rownumber <> t2.rownumber
         and t1.typ = t2.typ
       WHERE t1.mycarr= 73
         and t1.typ = 'S'
         and t1.digitsmax >= t2.digitsmin
         and t1.digitsmin <= t2.digitsmax;
```

Based upon your four sample rows this would return 12 rows instead of the 7 that your original query returns. But, as I understand it that is correct as each of those rows overlap the others.